# Как создать событие тачскрина (тап\сдвиг)

Tags: события, android, java

При помощи MotionEvent иммитирую события click в координатах x y внутри приложения

```
    void simulateEventDown( Activity yourActivity , long x, long y ) {
    MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                   SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                                   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
                                   x, y, 0);
    yourActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
```

}

применение

```
         simulateEventDown(MyApp.this, X,Y);
```

**Вопрос: как сделать то-же самое только в чужом активити, которое текущее в данный момент?**
Может из сервиса?

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно иметь на руках указатель/handle на текущий `Activity` и все будет работать. Вопрос в том, где брать этот указатель.

Один из способов: создаете кастомный класс `Application` в котором держите указатель на текущий активити:

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
        public void onCreate() {
              super.onCreate();
        }

        private Activity currentActivity = null;

        public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
              return currentActivity;
        }
        public void setCurrentActivity(Activity currentActivity){
              this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
        }

        public void simulateEventDown(Activity yourActivity , long x, long y ) {
              if(yourActivity==null) {
                 Log.w("Simulate", "No current activity - nothing to simulate);
                 return;
              }
              MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                               SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                               MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
                               x, y, 0);
              yourActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
 }
  }
```

Только не забудьте продекларировать MyApplication в манифесте
Далее, во всех своих активити (или как вариант в корневом своем активити) пишете нечто вроде:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected MyApplication myApp;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMyApp = (MyApp)this.getApplicationContext();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {        
        super.onDestroy();
        mMyApp.setCurrentActivity(null);
    }
}
```

Теперь достаточно в любом месте вызвать:
`((MyApp)getApplicationContext()).simulateEventDown()` - и все будет.